# How to get all the `font-family` URLs of a page using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

**<link>**

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

**@import**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Georama:wght@100&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');
```

**p element**

```
p {
    font-family: 'Style Script', arial;
}
```

For styling an external `font-family`, you can use `<link>` or `@import`.

How do I get all the URLs that were computed on the page and that point to the external `font-family` stylesheets?

Expected output:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Georama:wght@100&display=swap
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap
```

Comment: You can access <link> elements and style rules via DOM methods. Did you try anything yourself so far?

Comment: How can I tell if the `href` content is an external `font-family` URL or a JS?

Comment: It's never a JS since those use `src`. But it could be a regular stylesheet. When you access these, you can access the individual rules. Then you just gotta look for `@font-face` rules.

Comment: Understand. I'm a beginner. I did not know that. I will solve this with the DOM

Comment: Hmm, it's not as simple as I thought. For once, you cannot access rules if the stylesheet is from another domain: https://jsfiddle.net/hr2amb4j/ You can check its `href` though. Also, why do you need this?

Comment: I need the code to copy exactly the `font-family` used on one page and insert the same CSS on another page.

The intent is to make the new page look exactly like the original page.

As you can see in the example I showed above, if the URL doesn't exist or has errors, the `Style Script` will be replaced by `arial`. This is bad.

Comment: I made a change to your code. Will this always work?
https://jsfiddle.net/7w4zs9jr/

Comment: You can see in the console output that it also lists the fourth stylesheet URL, which isn't a font one. In what context are you going to copy the fonts? The code we have right now only works if it's included in the source page, but that also means it doesn't have access to the other page. This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/), can you be more specific? What pages are we talking about? Your own? Some 3rd party's?

Comment: I believe the problem has already been resolved. The fourth URL in the style sheet is not a problem as the code will only be in the source page. I will implement this in a `Google Chrome` extension. I found out what an xy problem is. It's very funny. Thanks for the help, you were very helpful.